# How to display Element with same type attribute in HTML ul in XML XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have Xml file with books element that have a type attribute, I want to display type and all Elements with same type within UL LI html like this:

1. Type1

   - book1
   - book2
2. Type2

   - book3
   - book4
3. this is my xml code:

[Xml file in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paM2L.png)
and my xslt:
[Xslt file in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04IwB.png)

> any help I will be appreciated?

Comment: Please share the input XML and the XSLT code that you have tried so far.

Comment: It sounds like a grouping problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of `grouping` (as rightly pointed out by @Martin Honnen) and since you are using XSLT 1.0, would require a `<xsl:key>` to be defined and then used for grouping.

As the grouping is to be done on `<titre>`, the key will be defined as

```
<xsl:key name="keyTitre" match="livre" use="titre" />
```

Next we loop through all the `<livre>` elements that are grouped using the key.

```
<xsl:for-each select="livre[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyTitre', titre)[1])]">
```

Lastly, a nested loop for the grouped keys.

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('keyTitre', titre)">
```

Below is the complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="keyTitre" match="livre" use="titre" />

    <xsl:template match="bibliotheque">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="livre[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyTitre', titre)[1])]">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:value-of select="titre" />
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('keyTitre', titre)">
                            <li>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(auteur/nom, ' ', auteur/prenom)" />
                            </li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ul>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT when run on the input XML produces the below result. Since the input XML has 3 different values for `<titre>` there are 3 `<ul>` elements in the output.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            t1
            <li>n1 p1</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            t2
            <li>n2 p2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            t3
            <li>n3 p3</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```